# FlashDevelop Java 32-bit problem - No Debugger

Tags: java, flashdevelop

While it seams a simple edit to the JVM.config to make FlashDevelop use the 32bit JRE, that doesn't seam to work for me..

I've just had to reinstall stuff and FlashDevelop doesn't want to allow debuging. It displays trace outputs but not debugging.

> Debugger startup error. For troubleshooting see:
> http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=F.A.Q Error
> details: net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIException: Can't initialize jni4net.
> (32bit vs 64bit JVM vs CLR ?) CLR architecture: 32bit JAVA_HOME:
> C:\Program Files\Java\jre6 ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An
> attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)    at
> net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.Dll.JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(JavaVMInitArgs*
> args)    at net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.Init()    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---    at net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.Init()    at
> net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNI.CreateJavaVM(JavaVM& jvm, JNIEnv& env, Boolean
> attachIfExists, String[] options)    at
> net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.CreateJVM()    at
> net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.CreateJVM(BridgeSetup setup)    at
> FlashDebugger.DebuggerManager.Start(Boolean alwaysStart)

FlashDevelop is 32bit. Now, I change the jvm.config to use the 32bit installation and now I get:

> Starting java as: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java -Xmx4000m
> -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true -Dapplication.home="C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\lib\fcsh.jar" INITIALIZING: E Could not create the Java virtual machine. Build
> halted with errors (fcsh).

so I seam stuck with either no debugging, or no running at all. Any ideas? all I seam to find is just to do the edit and not use version 8.. which the edit fails, and its setting to version 6..

Thanks